# EmberJS: undefined is not function on helper when content changed

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I got an error like these below when I trigger `destroyRecord()` on file `app/controllers/transactions.js`.

[image]

Below are my files.

**app/templates/transactions.emblem**

```
div
    format-datetime model.created_at
    bs-button clicked='destroyRecord' clickedParamBinding='model' size='xs' icon='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' type='danger' title='Delete'
```

**app/helpers/format-datetime.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function formatDatetime(input) {
  if ( input ) {
    return '%@/%@/%@'.fmt(input.getDate(), input.getMonth()+1, input.getFullYear());
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(formatDatetime);
```

**app/controllers/transactions.js**

```
....
actions: {
  destroyRecord: function() {
    if ( confirm('Are you sure to delete?') ) {
      this.get('model').destroyRecord();
      this.transitionToRoute('index');
    }
  }
....
```

But when I change file `app/helpers/format-datetime.js` to:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function formatDatetime(input) {
  if ( input ) {
    return input; // look this 
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(formatDatetime);
```

No error occured. So I guess my mistake is on my helper file. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `getDate`, `getMonth` or `getFullYear` isn't defined on input, toss a debugger there and find out what input is.

```
export function formatDatetime(input) {
  if ( input ) {
    console.log(input);
    debugger;
    return '%@/%@/%@'.fmt(input.getDate(), input.getMonth()+1, input.getFullYear());
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It throws error because `input` is a string, so I convert to `Date` and everything is fine. Here is the correct answer: `return '%@/%@/%@'.fmt(new Date(input).getDate(), new Date(input)getMonth()+1, new Date(input)getFullYear());`